# hiding an option in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular and trying the ng-options.  In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.permissionLevels = [
    { value: "ROLE_READ", text: "Read Only" },
    { value: "ROLE_WRITE", text: "Write" }
];
```

In my template, I have:

```
<select ng-options="permissionLevel.text for permissionLevel in permissionLevels"
        ng-model="selectedValue"></select>
```

Depending on the view, I want to hide either Read or Write.  So in my controller, I have another flag that indicates what view it is.  Before I used ng-options, I had a normal select drop down and did something like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Read Only </option>
    <option ng-show="shouldShowWrite">Write </option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to do this with ng-options?  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you manipulate the array `$scope.permissionLevels` depending on the view?

Comment: If the array is used in more than one place then changing it may have unwanted side-effects.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use a filter in the ngOptions expression:

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue"
        ng-options="permissionLevel.text for permissionLevel in 
                    permissionLevels | filter:shouldShow">
</select>
```

and define the shouldShow() function to $scope in the controller:

```
$scope.shouldShow = function (permissionLevel) {
  // put your authorization logic here
  return $scope.permission.canWrite || permissionLevel.value !== 'ROLE_WRITE';
}
```

For the full example see: http://plnkr.co/edit/8FkVktDXKGg3MQQawZCH

Answer (score 2):

Consider ngRepeat for that level of control.  I don't think it's possible with ngOptions.

```
 <select ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option ng-repeat="permissionLevel in permissionLevels" value="{{permissionLevel.text}}" ng-show="shouldShowWrite(permissionLevel)">
      {{permissionLevel.text}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score -4):

***Plaese check below code, it may help you to solve the problem!!***

```
<select>
<option>Read Only </option>
<option ng-show="selectedValue.value=='ROLE_WRITE'">Write </option>
</select>
```

Comment: The question states that this method has already been used and something using ng-option is desired (if possible.)