# How to remove dynamically created dropdown option in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have posted my code. I want to remove `Kanhu` from my options.

See the working example.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function myCtrl ($scope) {
   $scope.userProfiles = [
     {id: 10, name: 'Chinmay'},
     {id: 27, name: 'Sanjib'},
     {id: 35, name: 'Kanhu'},
     {id: 38, name: 'Pradeepta'},
     {id: 39, name: 'Debsish'},
  ];
  $scope.selectedUserProfile= $scope.userProfiles[1].id;

  $scope.existingId = 35;
 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Name
  <select  id="requestorSite" ng-model="selectedUserProfile" ng-options="userProfile.id as userProfile.name for userProfile in userProfiles">
  </select>
  <br/>
  </div>
```

Here is 5 names coming in the dropdown but I want to remove `kanhu` from my dropdown options. Can you please say me how to remove that?

I have tried to use filter `userProfile.id as userProfile.name for userProfile in userProfiles | filter:{id: !existingId}` this one not working.

Comment: try this ans : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761281/hiding-an-option-in-ng-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use | filter: {id: '!' + existingId}

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function myCtrl ($scope) {
   $scope.userProfiles = [
     {id: 10, name: 'Chinmay'},
     {id: 27, name: 'Sanjib'},
     {id: 35, name: 'Kanhu'},
     {id: 38, name: 'Pradeepta'},
     {id: 39, name: 'Debsish'},
  ];
  $scope.selectedUserProfile= $scope.userProfiles[1].id;

  $scope.existingId = 35;
 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Name
  <select  id="requestorSite" ng-model="selectedUserProfile" ng-options="userProfile.id as userProfile.name for userProfile in userProfiles | filter: {id: '!' + existingId}">
  </select>
  <br/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, [Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/9590/)

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name
  <select  id="requestorSite" ng-model="selectedUserProfile" ng-options="userProfile.id as userProfile.name for userProfile in userProfiles | filter:'!Kanhu'">
</select>
<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to remove that selected option from dropdown, you can easily disallow user to select that value(is there any specific reason?), I'll keep it in dropdown but that option will be in disable.

**Markup**

```
<select id="requestorSite" 
  ng-model="selectedUserProfile" 
  ng-options="userProfile.id as userProfile.name disable when (userProfile.name == 'Kanhu') for userProfile in userProfiles">
</select>
```

[**Plunkr in action**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xkvI1QSHAMstAEXW6Ofl?p=preview) here

Similar [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32570923/2435473)

Comment: Thank you for answering. How to remove that element instead of disable?

Comment: @Chinu just the way other answer already did! I just suggested what  I felt efficient..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, using options instead:

Hope it helps =)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function myCtrl ($scope) {
   $scope.userProfiles = [
     {id: 10, name: 'Chinmay'},
     {id: 27, name: 'Sanjib'},
     {id: 35, name: 'Kanhu'},
     {id: 38, name: 'Pradeepta'},
     {id: 39, name: 'Debsish'},
  ];
  $scope.selectedUserProfile= $scope.userProfiles[1].id;

  $scope.existingId = 35;
 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Name
      <select id="requestorSite" ng-model="selectedUserProfile">
  <option ng-hide="userProfile.id == existingId" value="{{userProfile.id}}" ng-repeat="userProfile in userProfiles">{{userProfile.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  </div>
```