# How to filter values of <select> in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want to filter the values of a `<select>`.

I have a table with first column `<select>` .

For eg: object for the `<select>` is
JSON:

```
json1 = [{id: 1, name: 'ABC'}, {id: 2, name: 'DEF'}, {id: 3, name: 'XYZ'}, {id: 4, name: 'ASD'}, {id: 5, name: 'QWE'}]

json2 = [{id: 1, name: 'ABC'}, {id: 2, name: 'DEF'}]
```

My requirement is: We need to show values from json1 in ng-options but which object should not be there in json2.

For eg: First 2 rows will be filled with json2. So we need to provide options 'XYZ' 'ASD' and  'QWE' in the following rows.

Suppose if name '**XYZ**' is selected in the dropdown of the third row. then 4th row `<select>` should show only `'ASD', and 'QWE'`. Similarly what ever object selected in other rows shouldn't be shown in option of other rows dropdown.

I have tried something like this

```
 <select ng-model="obj"
         ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in json1 | myFilter:json2">
</select>
```

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function(json2) {
return function(json1) {
  var filtered = []; 

  json1.forEach((d) => {
   var exists = false;
      json2.forEach((ad) => {
         if(ad.id == d.id) {
           exists = true;
         }
      });
    if(!exists) filtered.push(d);
  });
  console.log(filetered); 
  return filtered.length > 0 ? filtered : json1;
};
});
```

In filter console.log() values are filtered correctly as expected. However in ng-options all options from json1 are still available not updated with filtered values.

What's wrong?

Comment: please note not to use the `angular` tag for angularjs. `angular` refers to 2+

Comment: @Pranav, Yes it prints the expected result. But still dropdown shows all options instead of filtered options

Comment: **Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!** The `console.log` has a spelling error. And the construction of the filter is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

For example:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Unique</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
        <td>
            <select ng-model="product.unique" ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in (json1 | myfilter:products:$index)">
                <option value="">No select</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td ng-bind="product.name"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
vm.products = [{name: 'Product 1'}, {name: 'Product 2'}, {name: 'Product 3'}, {name: 'Product 4'}, {name: 'Product 5'}];
vm.json1 = [{id: 1, name: 'ABC'}, {id: 2, name: 'DEF'}, {id: 3, name: 'XYZ'}, {id: 4, name: 'ASD'}, {id: 5, name: 'QWE'}];
```

---

```
App.filter('myfilter' , [function() {
    return function(json1, products, index) {
        // Filter all products, except the mime
        productsFilter = products.filter(function(product, i) {
                return i !== index;
        });

        // filter those that have not yet been selected
        var json1Filter = json1.filter(function(item) {

            // ask if there is the id in a product
            return !productsFilter.some(function(product) {
                return item.id == product.unique;
            });
        });
        return json1Filter;
    };
}]);
```

Example Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vMJyLz

Answer (score -1):

I think you have the parameters to your filter slightly wrong. The filter function takes a first parameter as the value to be filtered and the other parameters are the ones after `myFilter:`.

I'm not 100% sure what you want to happen here, but your filter function is called for each value in the dropdown list and should return a replacement for the given value.

However, your code is returning an array of items. This is not how a filter works in AngularJS.

Your filter needs to be updated to check if the item being passed into the filter should be shown or not, and if not, return `false`.

You can look at the [script example from the AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) to see how they show to do this, or this other [Stack Overflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761281/hiding-an-option-in-ng-options).

Comment: Your answer confuses a [Custom Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) with the [built-in filter named `filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: @georgeawg If you see I link to the custom filter. I just used the poorly named filter name of `filter`